# trying to determine if user is a page admin using FB GraphAPI

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have a page tab app. When the user clicks on the "Go to App" and is sent to my page tab edit url i am trying to determine if they are a page admin or not.
I have tried two different methods. I have tried from the only admin/owner of the page
method 1 used from https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/09/05/platform-updates--labor-day-edition/

```
 $page_info = $facebook->api("/".$pageID."?fields=access_token");
 $pageAccessToken = $page_info['access_token']     

 $is_admin_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" . $pageID 
  . "/admins/" . $FBuser . "?access_token=" 
  . $pageAccessToken;

$response = file_get_contents($is_admin_url);
```

response is {"data":[]}

I have also tried::

```
path = '/'.$pageID.'/admins/'.$FBuser;
$params = array(
        'app_id' => FB_APP_ID,
        'access_token' => $pageAccessToken
);
$is_admin = $facebook->api($path, 'POST', $params);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although `PAGE_ID/admins` is a valid request, you need an admin's access_token to see the list. I.e. only admins can see who else is an admin.

What you can do is approach this from the other end by yielding a list of pages that the user is an admin of (using the `https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/accounts/` data and the `manage_pages` permission) and search through that list for your application.

However, I would understand if some users would be reluctant to give the `manage_pages` permission, as it also provides an access token to authenticate as that page, which would be something of a security hole on their part. Unfortunately, there does not seem to be another way to access a list of pages for which that user is an admin.

Comment: actually i do have a question about this answer. I got it to work, but  in the results i see in the response array a [paging] with a URL.
When do i need to use this and how can i tell when to use it?

Comment: Each request will only return a certain amount of items. If there are items available, use the URL given in the `paging.previous` or `paging.next` vars to access more items.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way will be signed Request.

A signed_request parameter is POSTed to an application when the app is loaded inside a Page Tab.

You can get a lot of information from signed_request

```
require '../fb_sdk/facebook.php';
$config = array();
$config['appId'] = '45916xxxxxx';
$config['secret'] = '59caxxxxxx';

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
```

`print_($signed_request);` will have output like

```
Array
(
    [algorithm] => HMAC-SHA256
    [expires] => 1347210000
    [issued_at] => 1347203265
    [oauth_token] => AAAGhmv67ki8BAAfBwtxxxx
    [page] => Array
        (
            [id] => 192430xxxxxx
            [liked] => 1
            [admin] => 1
        )

    [user] => Array
        (
            [country] => in
            [locale] => en_US
            [age] => Array
                (
                    [min] => 21
                )

        )

[user_id] => 10000020xxxxx
)
```

You can use `$signed_request[page][admin]` value to determine whether a user is admin of current page, in which your app in loaded in Page Tab. If it's set to `1` then user is admin of the page else not an admin i.e. set to `0`.

[**More About Signed Request**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/)

Comment: i do not get a signed request when the user does the follow:
1)goes to the page.
2)clicks on manage permissions
3)click on apps
4)clicks on "Go To App" which calls the URL set in the app for edit

All i get sent is 
MY_URL?fb_page_id=THE_FBPAGEID

Comment: `$signed_request[page]` will only be available in page tabs not on canvas.

Answer (score 0):

i had some luck using `admin_only` = true

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/groups/